# Azure Service Bus Topic Subscription - Filter on JSON-encoded message body property

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics

If the body of a BrokeredMessage is JSON text, is it possible to setup a Topic Subscription with a filter on properties within that JSON?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could promote those properties with their value into custom properties and use a [SqlFilter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.sqlfilter.sqlexpression.aspx) with user scoping.

Comment: 6 years 10 months to Accept 

Comment: Eventual consistency 

Comment: how is this done? tearing my hair out :(

Comment: What's "this"? Promotion or filtering? Filtering is documented. See the link above. Promotion is just taking a value from the body/payload and attaching it to the message properties (headers) upon sending.